# White screen and can't activate themes and plugins

Tags: plugins, themes

I have a newly installed [Wordpress website](http://travelagentsites.com/). The problem is the front end is just showing a white blank screen. I can access the admin dashboard, and when I went to Themes I got this error.

> ERROR: The theme directory "twentyfourteen" does not exist.

[image]

I can install a theme, but I can't activate them and everytime I try I always get this message.

> Cheatin uh

Same thing for plugins, I can install a plugin but I can't activate them and I always get this message...

> The plugin does not have a valid header.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems you do not have the `twentyfourteen` theme which may be currently active. Have you tried by putting the default `twentyfourteen` theme inside themes folder?

Comment: the Wordpress is fresh install and I have a `twentyfourteen` in the theme directory.

Comment: If its a fresh installation, then it should not be a problem. Try checking your site's error logs for a more specific error message. Your hosts should be able to help you accessing your site's error logs.

Comment: thanks @Chittaranjan I do asked for a help from the hosting support. It is now running good, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: So what was the issue?